# Android Studio 0.3.1 Proguard Not Obfuscating

Tags: java

It looks like any APK files created in Android Studio are easily decompiled by using www.limelect.com/android/ utility to quickly reverse engineer APK files.

Has anybody successfully obfuscated their APK files in Android Studio?

There does not seem to be anybody home at google with a comment about this, even though I tried to send messages using Google Groups to anybody on the Android Tool team.

I am able to Build -> Generate Signed APK -> (Gradle dialog) (Push OK) -> Generate Signed APK Wizard -> Run Proguard CHECKED and enter the path to proguard-android.txt file in the config file paths dialog.

The file is generated OK, but the source Java file is easily decompiled and inspected.

If anybody has succeeded using Android Studio and were able to obfuscate your code, definitely post a copy of your proguard-android-txt file.

Here are some links that describe this:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generate-signed-apk-wizard-specify-apk-location.html
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

Also, does anybody know how to create a proguard output log to see what config options actually took hold and what decision it made for each file on the project?

->#This is a sample proguard-android.txt configuration file for ProGuard that I tried:

-verbose
-dontpreverify
-printmapping
-printconfiguration
-repackageclasses ''
-optimizationpasses 7
-allowaccessmodification
-># The -optimizations option disables some arithmetic simplifications that Dalvik 1.0 and 1.5 can't handle.
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good tutorial with a working proguard example in Android Studio 
http://responsiveandroid.com/2014/12/10/android-proguard-tutorial.html

This issue may not be in your proguard but you build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like much of the Generate Signed APK options don't actually do anything: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56532. Which was also my experience.